# how can i sort a matrix more efficiently?(c++)

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, matrix

Im trying to sort a matrix, but my code seems excessively long, complex, and inefficient.
Im sure that there are better and more efficient ways to sort a matrix, But as hard as im trying, I cant find them. If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it

I tried to initialize an array

```
temp
```

and copy every element in the matrix to it, then sorted the array(bubble sort), and then copied the sorted array back to the matrix. This process is longer than i thought i'd be.

```cpp
int main()
{
    // Matrix initialization
    int matrix[row][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            cin >> matrix[i][j];

    // Building an array and copying the matrix elements to the array
    int temp[row* col];
    int nextRow = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= row* col; i++)
    {
        if (i - (col* nextRow) < row)
            temp[i] = matrix[nextRow][i - (col* nextRow)];
        else if (i - (col* nextRow) == row)
        { 
            i--;
            nextRow++;
        }
    }
    
    //Bubble sorting the array
    for (int i = 0; i + 1 < row * col; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j  + 1 < (row * col) - i; ++j)
        {
            if (temp[j] > temp[j + 1])
            {
                int t = temp[j];
                temp[j] = temp[j + 1];
                temp[j + 1] = t;
            }
        }
    }

    //Copying back the elements from the array to the matrix
    nextRow = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row * col; ++i)
    {
        if (i % row == 0)
            nextRow++;
        matrix[nextRow][i - (col * nextRow)] = temp[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bubble sort is O(n²), so that's very slow even on medium-sized arrays. Use `std::sort` instead, which typically uses an O(n log n) algorithm.

Comment: You can skip reading into the 1st matrix and read straight into the array to be sorted.  You can replace the bubble sort with `std::sort`

Comment: Instead of loop and copying element 1 by 1, just do `std::memcpy` or `std::copy`. Then use `std::sort`. If you want to be more fancy, you can create your `Matrix` class and implement iterators, which can be directly passed to `std::sort` algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using std::sort.

#include 
#include 
#include

int main()
{
// sizes of your matrix
static constexpr std::size_t rows_v{ 5ul };
static constexpr std::size_t cols_v{ 5ul };

```
// initialize your matrix with values
// I like using std::array (easier to pass around to functions) 

//int matrix[rows_v][cols_v] // you can still use "C" style array, but I use std::array
std::array<std::array<int, cols_v>, rows_v> matrix{{ // remove one bracket here if you use "C" style array
    {1,2,3,4,5},
    {9,6,4,3,1},
    {6,7,3,2,3},
    {9,4,6,2,3},
    {3,0,4,2,1}
}};

// range based for loop that will return
// each row of the matrix one by one
// each row will be a reference to a std::array<int, cols_v>
// no need to type that, the compiler can figure out the type for you
for (auto& row : matrix)
{
    // sort each row from begin to end.
    // std::sort(std::begin(row),std::end(row)); // for "C" style array
    std::sort(row.begin(), row.end());
}

// then show the content
// this time by const& since we are only going to output values 
// not change them
for (const auto& row : matrix)
{
    for (const auto value : row)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: I think he wanted to sort all elements together, not row by row.

Comment: I must admit that wasn't exactly clear to me. If so it is probably better to make an array class with a one dimensional array (and then sorting that). And indexing getters/setters.